How do I fetch an API and display it on a custom Error 404 Page?
I'm trying to build a custom error 404 page that displays a random Chuck Norris joke on it, but even though typing in the wrong URL makes the error page show up, Thymeleaf doesn't render the Chuck Norris joke. I tried troubleshooting it by replacing root.get("value").asText() with "Hello World!" as the second argument in model.addAttribute to make sure it was working, but it wasn't rendered on the page either. Even attempting to debug the error method with System.out.Println hasn't worked because nothing is printed to the terminal whenever a request is made to the error page. Just in case it's relevant, I wrote server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false in application.properties to get rid of the WhiteLabel error page and display my custom error page instead.
How do I get my error page to receive data from the API and display it with Thymeleaf? Am I doing something wrong that I'm not seeing? I'm fairly new to SpringBoot.
ErrorController.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@RestController
public class ErrorController {
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error(Model model) {
        try {
            String url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=history";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String jsonListResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonListResponse);

            model.addAttribute("quote", root.get("value").asText());

            return "error";
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);

            model.addAttribute("quote", "Chuck Norris broke the joke.");

            return "error";
        }
    }
}

error.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Error 404</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 data-th-text="${quote}"></h1>
</body>
</html>


I briefly reviewed your problem description and noticed that you want to return a Thymeleaf view, but in your code, you're using @RestController, which is provided by Spring to return JSON data, not view names.
The solution is to replace @RestController with @Controller.
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error(Model model) {
        try {
            String url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=history";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String jsonListResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonListResponse);

            model.addAttribute("quote", root.get("value").asText());

            return "error";
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);

            model.addAttribute("quote", "Chuck Norris broke the joke.");

            return "error";
        }
    }
}

This is my first time answering a question, and I hope it helps. Please forgive me if there are any mistakes.
